# f:ajax render becomes slower and slower

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I have a performance issue with my JSF page and can not find an solution. I'm using JSF 2.0.
I click on an element to render another element :

```
<f:ajax event="click" listener="#{row.select}" render=":dataWrapper"/>
```

After click the data panel will be rendered. My problem is when I click on the element again. The data panel will be rendered too, but it will takes more time. If I click the third time the rendering needs again more time. And so on ...

What can be the reason for this?

I checked the request with the Firefox debugger and everything looks fine, except the reponse time.
The response time will grow up every request.

Comment: What JSF impl/version? Tried the latest impl version? Tried an alternative impl?

Comment: Hello BalusC, thanks for your response.We can not change the JSF version. Update : when we load the page again, and starting with the first click, than we have the same response time. But with every new click the reponse time will be grow up.

Comment: At least tell the JSF impl/version used. Then we can tell if it's a bug in JSF impl/version used or not. Otherwise we can only do shooting in the dark which isn't helpful to you and future users struggling with the same problem which found your question while searching for answers.

Comment: Sorry BalusC, we are using : Mojarra JSF API (javax.faces/2.0) 2.0.2-FCS

Comment: Thank you. Well, Mojarra 2.0.2, wow that's a pretty ancient version from 26 december 2009. I haven't tested it, but I really wouldn't be surprised if this problem is fixed for long in the current version. Really so many state saving and performance related issues have been fixed in the period of almost 4 years. If I were you, I'd for testing purposes deploy the project to a test server utilizing the current 2.1.26 version and retry. If it fixes the problem for you, then you know that it's caused by sticking to an ancient library version.

Comment: Yes, we will do that.

Comment: Hello BalusC, we find a server with Mojarra JSF Implementation (javax.faces/2.1) 2.1.6 and we have the same problem.

Comment: Problem solved with latest jsf version.